# How can I stream CSV file into JSON and view in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, json, laravel, csv, routes

I'm having fun with Laravel 5.8. 
I have a CSV file to stream as JSON and then view on the blade template.
Someone could help me fixing this script?
Sorry but I'm new to web developing.

```
public function getFlyer() {
    // Decode CSV data in JSON and send it to the view
    $response = new StreamedResponse(function(){
    // Open output stream
    $handle = fopen('C:\xampp\htdocs\testWeb\flyers_data.csv', 'w');

    // Add CSV headers
    fputcsv($handle, [
        'id',
        'title', 
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
        'is_published',
        'retailer',
        'category'
    ]);

    // Get all flyers
    foreach (Flyer::all() as $flyer) {
        // Add a new row with data
        fputcsv($handle, [
            $flyer->id,
            $flyer->title,
            $flyer->start_date,
            $flyer->end_date,
            $flyer->is_published,
            $flyer->retailer,
            $flyer->category
        ]);
    }

    // Close the output stream
    fclose($handle);
}, 200, [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="flyers_data.csv"',
    ]);
        return view($response);
}
```

}

This is my route

```
Route::get('api/flyers', 'FlyersController@getFlyer', function(){
  // Paginate data and set URI
  $pagination = Controller\FlyersController::paginate(100)
  ->withPath('custom/url');
});
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you wanting to return JSON or a CSV file?

Comment: From csv to Json. But I want to use StreamedResponse in laravel as to avoid to load the file and exhausting the cache.